# When starting eclipse using sudo, avd is stored in the wrong folder

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

In order to get eclipse to run properly on Ubuntu 14, I need to start the program using sudo eclipse.

I create an AVD and it stores it in the folder: /root/.android/avd/test.avd

But when I try to start the avd through the AVD manager I get the following error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'test'
PANIC: Could not find test.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd
```

So, eclipse is looking for the AVD in the wrong folder. I tried a variety of ways around this, but it seems that it should not be that hard to just get eclipse to look in a different folder for the AVD, or to change the folder that the AVD is created in.

Comment: Maybe you need to start the manager with superuser permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from when you are updating Eclipse or installing new packages in Eclipse, you do not need to start Eclipse as `sudo` to develop an android app. Change the owner of the folder that Eclipse is stored in using `sudo chown <non-root-user> -R <installation-directory-of-Eclipse>` so it gets the avd from the correct folder or better still, change the permissions of Eclipse's installation folder using `chmod`.